# How can I enable history completion by program in terminator as guake has it?

Tags: command-line, history, guake, terminator

In guake I can type `ls UP-ARROW` and it will show `ls /home/blah` for example. In terminator using up arrow after typing `ls` just brings me to the command I entered prior.  Is there any way to enable this in terminator / what is this functionality called? I use zsh by the way.

Answer (score 1):

If you use bash, you can add the following to your ~/.inputrc

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
```

If you use zsh, you can add the following to your ~/.zshrc

```
bindkey "^[[A" history-search-backward
bindkey "^[[B" history-search-forward
```

Comment: I actually use zsh but this is exactly what I meant.

Comment: @jett I think you want `bindkey “^[[A" history-search-backward` and `bindkey "^[[B" history-search-forward` then

Comment: hm.. I applied it but no avail.

Comment: @jett in your ~/.zshrc? Sorry, didn't list that earlier; zsh doesn't care about ~/.inputrc.

Comment: yes at the bottom of my zshrc. It doesn't have any noticeable affect.